# How to create a customized repository for websphere (Application server)?

Tags: websphere-8

I want to create a customized repository for websphere and publish that URL using IHS server.(preferably i want to do it in Windows server ) so that i can use that link to access binaries for installations/upgrades/patchings from other servers(Linux/Solaris) in my environment. Can anyone please provide the process ?

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you post it? Otherwise, you'd better read something about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Application Server install and maintenance is managed with a tool called IBM Installation Manager (IIM).  There is an optional tool called PUCL (Packaging Utility Commnad Line) that allows you to mirror existing repositories into directories that are directly usable over ftp:// and http://

A good summary of PUCL relative to WebSphere is available here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1201_seelemann/1201_seelemann.html

> You can use the IBM Packaging Utility to create custom or “enterprise”
>   IBM Installation Manager repositories that contain multiple products
>   and maintenance levels that fit the needs of your business. As an
>   administrator, you can control the content of your enterprise
>   repository, which then can serve as the central repository to which
>   your organization connects to perform product installations and
>   updates. IBM Packaging Utility essentially copies from a set of source
>   IBM Installation Manager repositories to a target repository and
>   eliminates duplicate artifacts, helping to keep the repository size as
>   small as possible. You can also delete (or “prune”) a repository,
>   removing maintenance levels or products that are no longer needed. IBM
>   Packaging Utility 1.5.0.1 can be downloaded at no cost from the IBM
>   Support Portal.

```
   $ PUCL copy com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v80 –repositories
 http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v80 -target D:\WASBase8001
```